# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Tag") to str

Tags: python, requests, telebot

Я знаю почему ошибка, но не знаю как её исправить.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import telebot
from telebot import types

@bot.message_handler(commands=['course'])
def course_message(message):
    response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
    page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    currency = []
    for h in soup.select('span.inline-stocks__value_inner'):
        currency.append(h)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'USD: ' + currency[0])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'EUR: ' + currency[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите текст из найденного HTML элемента:

```
currency.append(h.text)
```